# How can I get rid of chrome console error?

Tags: javascript, console

[image: promlem]

I'm learning `JS`. When I run `Chrome`, this error is keeping appearing every time, I disable some options in `Kaspersky`, but nothing changed. Then, although I uninstalled `Kaspersky`, the same error.

```
GET http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/(long link)
net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is a kaspersky chrome extension causing this, try to disable this extension and the error will disappear